# Angular DI injected singletons or classes in vanilla classes

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I'm still really new to Angular, so this may be a dumb question, but as I'm porting my AngularJS application to Angular, I keep running into scenarios where I want a class that I can just instantiate, but I need to use injected services within that class. I feel I must be missing a best practice and so am seeking your help!

As a concrete example, that pops up a lot, I'm using the logger library [ngx-logger](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-logger) to replace $log. Then I'll have a utility class, let's say some state manager that is passed around, and I want to write a log message to the ngx-logger. I want this to be the same instance that everything else is logging to, for consolidation of log messages.

Any thoughts, suggested readings or good examples would be greatly appreciated. If it's helpful, I'm presently developing with Typescript and Angular 6.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you have a service instantiate the logger and keep one instance, and have everyone go through that service?

Comment: `new StateManager(this.logger)`?

Comment: @FrankModica How would a vanilla class get that instance without injection?

Comment: @JB Nizet that is how I've been doing it to date, but if feels like an anti-pattern because it was cluttering up the constructor, so I thought I would get feedback.

Comment: I was thinking a service would have any dependencies injected into it by Angular, and it could pass them to the class it needs to instantiate and hold one instance of that class. Then everyone goes through the service. But perhaps I've misunderstood the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Actually what you are looking for is `Providers` in terms of `Angular`. That is something you can change any point of time and you need to change it in one places. Mostly the providers are used to configure `app`, `plugin` or `modules`.

Visit to this official docs - https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-providers

Comment: How does a provider help me when I'm trying to instantiate a vanilla class? Isn't that what you would do if you wanted to inject an existing instantiation into something that is injected? (a service or component for example)